# Magento 1.9.3 Advanced Admin Login is Case Sensitive

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm about to put a site live and I altered the following within the admin on Magento 1.9.3
`System>Advanced>Admin>Security>Login` is Case Sensitive to equal Yes

It kicked me out of the admin immediately and now I can't login back in using my username and password?

I have tried the following:
clearing all sessions, cache via FTP
changed the bruteforce settings in bruteforce.ini
running the following SQL to alter my password:

> UPDATE admin_user SET `password` = CONCAT(MD5('lemein'), ':23') WHERE
>   `username` = 'admin';

I can't get access to the admin, is there away to reset Login is Case Sensitive back to NO via the database or code so I can get back in to the admin section?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use sql query to update core_config_data where this value is stored:

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 0 WHERE `path` = 'admin/security/use_case_sensitive_login';
```